# async function triggers setstate before await is complete

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, async-await

setLoading gets called before all the data gets fetched. How do I ensure that setLoading is called only after the for loop that fetches the data is completed? Also is it even advisable to combine async data with non async data? What I'm trying to achieve is to render a timeline with each event accompanied with their respective directions(which is the async data)

```
const Schedule = (props) => {
const [events, setEvents] = React.useState([]);
const [visible, setVisible] = React.useState(false);
const [unsatisfied, setUnsatisfied] = React.useState("");
const [timingsArray, setTimingsArray] = React.useState([]);
const [isLoading, setLoading] = React.useState(true);


React.useEffect(() => {
            directionsArray(props.initRoutes, props.timings, props.data);
        }, []);

const directionsArray = async (allRoutes, timings, data) => {
    let result = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < allRoutes.length - 1; i++) {
        let obj = { distance: "", duration: "", steps: [] };
        let steps = [];
        let distance = "";
        let duration = "";
        let origin =
            typeof allRoutes[i] === "object"
                ? allRoutes[i].lat + "," + allRoutes[i].long
                : allRoutes[i];
        let destination = allRoutes[i + 1];
        try {
            let resp = await fetch(
                "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=" +
                    origin +
                    "&destination=" +
                    destination +
                    "&key=" +
                    GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY +
                    "&mode=transit&region=sg"
            );
            //console.log(JSON.stringify(await resp.json()));
            let data = (await resp.json())["routes"][0]["legs"][0];
            let response = data["steps"];
            distance = data["distance"]["text"];
            duration = data["duration"]["text"];

            for (let j = 0; j < response.length; j++) {
                steps.push(await routeFormatter(await response[j]));
            }
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
        obj.steps = steps;
        obj.distance = distance;
        obj.duration = duration;
        result.push(obj);
    }
    let updatedTimings = merge(timings, result);
    let combinedData = eventsWithDirections(updatedTimings, data, result);
    setTimingsArray(updatedTimings);
    setEvents(combinedData);
    setLoading(false);
};

if (isLoading) {
        return (
            <View
                style={{
                    flex: 1,
                    alignContent: "center",
                    justifyContent: "center",
                }}
            >
                <ActivityIndicator
                    style={{ alignSelf: "center" }}
                    size="large"
                />
            </View>
        );
    } else {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <View style={styles.body}>
                    <Modal animated visible={visible} animationType="fade">
                        <ActionOptions
                            onReselect={onReselect}
                            onClose={onClose}
                            unsatisfied={unsatisfied}
                            events={props.allEvents}
                            genres={props.genres}
                            newTimeChange={newTimeChange}
                            filters={props.filters}
                        />
                    </Modal>
                    <Timeline
                        onEventPress={(event) => onEventPress(event)}
                        data={events}
                        timeStyle={{
                            textAlign: "center",
                            backgroundColor: "#cc5327",
                            color: "white",
                            padding: 5,
                            borderRadius: 13,
                        }}
                      />
                </View>
                <View style={styles.footer}>{renderProceedButton()}</View>
            </View>
        );
    }
};
```

Comment: It is not clear what the problem is here. It looks like nothing is going to happen until the render *after* all of those set calls. What do you mean `setLoading` is called before the array is ready?

Comment: @JaredSmith I'm pushing the data I fetch into the result array, then I want to use that array to render my component, but setLoading is called before the array has the data from the API calls making the component render nothing.

Comment: Again, I don't know if there's a language barrier or a conceptual barrier or both but that isn't how that works at all.

Comment: try logging combinedData before `setEvents(combinedData);` to make sure it's what you're expecting it to be

Comment: @JaredSmith Sorry its probably a conceptual barrier on my part. I'm just trying to use a for loop that makes an API call on each iteration then wait until the for loop is over and call setstate on that array.

Comment: @RuiFeng You can use [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the issue here is that the loop that iterates over `allRoutes` needs to be wrapped in a `Promise.all`. Right now, in each iteration of the loop, the rest of the code in the `try` block will wait for the data to be fetched, but `setLoading` is called outside of that scope and is not being told to `await` anything else.

Instead of a for loop, maybe try having the iteration be something like

```
await Promise.all(allRoutes.map( (route) => {
  //code that's currently in the for loop
}))
```

Hope that makes sense. I found this post helpful on the subject matter as well: https://zellwk.com/blog/async-await-in-loops/